# For integers $n \neq 0$ is $\sin n$ irrational or transcendental?

Tags: irrational-numbers

For integers $n \neq 0$ is $\sin n$ irrational or transcendental?

This arose from  [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459685/is-sinn-leq1-or-sinn1-for-integer-n). I would hypothesize yes and yes, possibly with proof for irrationality existing and but not for the more difficult property of transcendentality.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299140/163 goes even further and shows the sine of any nonzero rational is transcendental

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, $\sin(n)$ is trascendental (hence irrational) by the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), since $2i\sin(n)=e^{in}-e^{-in}$.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thanks

Comment: @Jack : I think this difference of trascendentals being a trascendental deserves an explanation (for example $(e+5)-(e+4)=1$ and nobody knows if $\pi+e$ is trascendental or algebraic). Besides you have assumed that $e$ is trascendental which can be accepted as well known of course. Regards.

Comment: @Ataulfo: you got it the wrong way. I was not claiming that the difference of two trascendental number is trascendental, but that if we assume that $\sin(n)$ is algebraic, by exploiting De Moivre's identity we contradict the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem, Baker's formulation.

Comment: We may say it also in the following way: if $\sin(n)$ is algebraic, $e^i$ is algebraic. But $e^i$ is not algebraic, hence neither it is $\sin(n)$.

Comment: @Jack: I like more this last answer.Thanks.